# Atom not able to install auto-update-packages@1.0.0

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I was trying to install the auto-update-packages for Atom on Ubuntu but when I used the command

```
apm install auto-update-packages
```

which was the first step in [this](https://atom.io/packages/auto-update-packages) page it returned this error.

```
npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-30-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/usr/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/home/liam/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/home/liam/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/tmp/d-115528-3402-1fgbwlx/package.tgz" "--target=0.22.0" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: auto-update-packages@1.0.0
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /tmp/apm-install-dir-115528-3402-197s6zu/npm-debug.log
```

There is no /tmp/apm-install-dir-115528-3402-197s6zu/ directory, and so no file to show, though I assume it would just be the content of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message already tells you what's wrong. You are on Linux while the package requires Darwin, i.e. OSX.

---

This matches the metadata of the package:

https://github.com/yujinakayama/atom-auto-update-packages/blob/master/package.json#L9

```
  "os": [
    "darwin"
  ]
```

So as expeted, the package is only supported on OSX. There's actually an [open issue](https://github.com/yujinakayama/atom-auto-update-packages/issues/24) to add Windows and Linux support.